blender output from image sequence is very bad
I am trying to export a video from image sequence. The images are rendered in cycles and are of good quality however when i animate the image sequence in video editor, its comes out very bad and choppy.
render settings -1

render settings -2

screenshot of the video, you can see how bad it looks

sample image from while the video is created from


Do you have the same issue with H.264 as video codec ? I don't know MPEG (dvix).

In my experience divx does not produce a good quality, so as @Lutzi suggested, have you tried H.264?

Just as an aside, I've had problems with Lossless in the past and now use Perceptually Lossless 100% of the time

I'm pretty sure Divx is a lossy codec, so it doesn't have a Lossless option
